# Why do I get this error on Dynamics CRM - Error: Url does not contain MSCRMServices

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I got this problem that drove me crazy for a day or so.

Url does not contain MSCRMServices

I have a custom service that is attempting to access CRM.
I am using JavaScript to issue SOAP calls to the service but it fails and gives the error above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was my WebService was located in the ../CRMWeb/ISV/webservice1.asmx directory.

I relocated the WebService to ../CRMWeb/MSCRMServices/CustomISVServices/webservice1.asmx directory.

This should resolve your problem.